# How to run multiple command in a single line?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to run multiple commands on a single line, e.g

```
(gdb) info threads; c
Args must be numbers or '$' variables.
```

But it looks like gdb doesn't support so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `define` command to define your own command:

```
(gdb) define mycommand
Type commands for definition of "mycommand".
End with a line saying just "end".
>info threads
>c
>end
(gdb) mycommand
```

For detailed information, you can refer: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define.

Answer (score 2):

gdb doesn't have a syntax for this.  So, you can't do it.

If you want to be able to run canned sequences, see the "define" command.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by first putting the breakpoints and then use the "**command** inside GDB and mention all the commands which should gets executed when this particular breakpoints hits.  This way we can automate our debugging session as well.

**(gdb) help command**

*Set commands to be executed when a breakpoint is hit.
Give breakpoint number as argument after **"commands"**.
With no argument, the targeted breakpoint is the last one set.
The commands themselves follow starting on the next line.
Type a line containing **"end"** to indicate the end of them.
Give "silent" as the first line to make the breakpoint silent;
then no output is printed when it is hit, except what the commands print.*

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40113e: file thread.cpp, line 19.
(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000000000040113e in main() at thread.cpp:19
(gdb) commands 1
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>info locals
>print argc
>print argv
>backtrace
>end
(gdb) info b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000000000040113e in main() at thread.cpp:19
        info locals
        print argc
        print argv
        backtrace
(gdb)
```